# JBoss remote EJB client using global

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jndi

I am writing a remote client for an EJB running in JBoss AS EAP6.2. Following instructions in Section "7.5.1. Invoke a Session Bean Remotely using JNDI" in "JBoss EAP 6.2 Development Guide", I am able to access methods on the EJB if I use the JNDI name

`<ejb:/hibernate-ejb-server/UserBean!org.ktest.study.beans.UserBean`

but **fails if I use the global JNDI name** that is actually logged in the JBoss server logs

`java:global/hibernate-ejb-server/UserBean!org.ktest.study.beans.UserBean`

If I use the global JNDI name, I get the below exception

`Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial`

After searching on the web, I understand that I must provide some properties (related to javax.naming) to InitialContext while instantiating it. But I am not sure what these properties are. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

"java:global" will never work to access a remote server. Even when you execute it against a remote initial context, it will be resolved in the local JVM.

It's one of the many oddities associated with JNDI.